# Как настроить выход в интернет из гостевой FreeBSD 10 из VirtualBox на Windows 10?

Tags: windows, сеть, freebsd, virtualbox

Есть домашняя сеть: роутер `192.168.1.1` к которому подключен домашний комп с Windows 10 `192.168.1.5` и сервер с *FreeBSD 10.2* `192.168.1.7` на котором будет пара сайтов. Изначально планировал использовать его, но в процессе тестирования выяснилось, что он вряд ли справится с нагрузкой.

Установил FreeBSD 10 `(10.0.2.15)` на *Windows 10*. С настройками по-умолчанию (через NAT в VB) *freebsd* из виртуалки выходит в инет, но с хоста и локалки не видна. Нужно сделать так, чтобы на гостевая ось была доступна с локалки (для переноса данных со старого сервера freebsd), с хоста *Windows* по SSH, и из внешнего интернета. Пробовал ставить на виртуальном сетевом адаптере VB `192.168.1.10`, в настройках сетевой карты Win включал раздачу инета, в VB - тип сети в мост и в виртуальный сетевой адаптер, в гостевой *freebsd* ставил `192.168.1.11`, nameserver `192.168.1.1` - no `route to host.` Подскажите, как правильно все это сделать?

Comment: А сетевой мост кидал на существующую реальную сетевую карту или на виртуальную созданную виртуалбоксом?

Comment: Подумал, что т.к. все это на windows, то попробую на hyper-v - на нем все заработало.

Comment: Мне всё-таки было бы интересно разобраться с виртуалбоксом. Потому что у меня проблем с гостём\хостом и сетью проблем подобного рода за последние пару лет не было от слова "совсем".

Answer (score -1):

Заменил VirtualBox на Hyper-V - заработало без дополнительной настройки.

Comment: Необходимо сменить режим NAT на мост. И желательно посмотреть настройки сетевой карты после смены, таблицу маршрутизации и что в resolv.conf